# Creating an MFC that can run other dlls. Debug Assertion Failed after project is ran

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, mfc, dialog

I have 2 functioning dialog based projects. My goal now is to create another simple MAIN project, such that when the MAIN project in ran, 2 push buttons appear and when the user clicks on them, the respective 2 projects will appear.

I have added the 2 projects into the MAIN project. Converted them into .dll, added the .lib files into additional dependencies and included the paths.
I have also added the additional include paths so that i can include the .h of the 2 projects into the MAIN cpp file.

This is how part of my code looks like.
This is just a test, that's why I only included 1 project instead of 2.

```
enter code here

// MAIN3Dlg.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MAIN3.h"
#include "MAIN3Dlg.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"
#include "Resource3.h"
#include "test3Dlg.h"
.
.
.
void CMAIN3Dlg::OnBnClickedCancel()
{
    Ctest3Dlg TEST3_DIALOG;
    TEST3_DIALOG.DoModal();
}
```

The program can build, but when I run it, I get a debug assertion failed!
The error points to this line: `"ASSERT(AfxGetThread() == NULL);"`

How can I fix this, or I doing something wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using MFC classes in both a main executable and in a DLL can cause many, many problems, due to the way MFC is initialised. Generally, you would need to define your DLL as an `MFC Extension DLL` (even if you are not actually adding extensions), in order that all modules share the same MFC instance. This is **not** a trivial task.

You can get more information here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/extension-dlls?view=vs-2019

As far as I know, this is the ***only*** way you can switch control between your EXE and DLL(s) when both/all are concurrently using  MFC.

Comment: None of this is accurate. The only requirement is, that all executable images accessing MFC share the same copy of the MFC DLL implementations. You ensure this by linking against the same version of MFC. If you want to take advantage of MFC's state management, all you need to do is set up and restore the state environment at the DLL boundary (i.e. on entry and exit of every exported method). See [Managing the State Data of MFC Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/managing-the-state-data-of-mfc-modules).

Comment: @IInspectable - Where is the inaccuracy? I said "**Generally**, you would need to define your DLL as an MFC Extension DLL..." and, "**As far as I know**, this is the only way..." MFC state management is simpler when using Extension DLLs.

Comment: And note, the OP wishes to call an MFC-based class **defined** in the DLL from the EXE!

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265451/exporting-a-mfc-dialog-from-a-dll

Comment: I don't know, what the OP is trying to accomplish, and the question is insufficient in communicating this. With that said, an Extension DLL may or may not be a solution, but if it is, it's certainly not the only solution.